# How to get a unit relative to the size of the screen in androidx.compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am looking for something similar like [`vh` in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length). But I can not find it in the [`androidx.compose.ui.unit`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/package-summary). What is the right way to do it in Jetpack?

Comment: If you don't need the value itself you can  set dimensions of your composable as percent of parent with
`Modifier.fillMaxWidth/Height/Size(fraction)`, `fraction` is float between 0f and 1f to cover percentage of available space of parent.

Comment: You can use a `BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){}`. Within the scope of the BoxWithConstraints you will get the height and width of the screen, provided it is the root composable in your Activity/Fragment